# What is the simplest correct way to get 'previous day at 15:00' in joda time

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime

Say I have a DateTime reference and I want to get time of previous day at 15:00.
If I say

```
DateTime someTime = ....;
DateTime yesterday1500 = someTime.toDateMidnight().toDateTime().minusDays(1).plusHours(15);
```

Then this will work on all days except when there is daylight savings change.
If someTime = '1.4.2014' I would get '31.3.2014 15:00'.
If someTime = '31.3.2014' I would get '30.3.2014 16:00'.

Best I could come up with is

```
yesterday1500 = new DateTime(someTime.getYear(), someTime.getMonthOfYear(), someTime.getDayOfMonth(), 15, 0, 0, 0);
```

It works fine but it seems clunky.
Is there a better way?

Edit:
I'm in Croatia which is CEST (UTC+01:00) time zone.

Edit 2:
Added ...toDateMidnight().toDateTime()... to example code to indicate that someTime can be at any point in time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty tidy:

```
DateTime dt = someTime.minusDays(1).withTime(15, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

@dcarapic, I have tried few versions of Joda, have not found your problem.

Just use your code, like:

*DateTime yesterday1500 = someTime.minusDays(1).plusHours(15);*

The output is like below, I also checked [two comings time saving moment](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html), your case does not occur either.

2014-01-04T00:00:00.000+08:00 |
2014-01-03T15:00:00.000+08:00

2014-03-31T00:00:00.000+08:00 |
2014-03-30T15:00:00.000+08:00

2014-09-26T00:00:00.000+08:00 |
2014-09-25T15:00:00.000+08:00

2014-09-28T00:00:00.000+08:00 |
2014-09-27T15:00:00.000+08:00

And, by the way, the withTime and plusHour both called withMillis to set the new hour. I do not see the difference. I have checked joda 2.4/1.6. So, what version are u using?

Comment: -1 There's no way that code works. Removing a day and adding 15 hours is not going to result in 3pm on the previous day.

Comment: I'm using Joda time 1.5.2.  
Note: I am not allowed to update to newer version. I can reproduce the problem with my timezone (+01:00). Could be that daylights savings changes at different time in your timezone. In my timezone it changes at 02:00.

Comment: dcarapic, ok, then that make sense. I will check it later. I am in China, we do not use time saving at all. Your cases do not occur on my code. That's truth. And, That's it. @Duncan, take it easy.

Comment: @kthinker What do you mean by "take it easy"? Your code is wrong - did you make an error while posting it? Perhaps you forgot the `toDateMidnight()`?